# Connect Android to SQL server over WIFI

Tags: android, sql

Im new to the Android application front and require a lot of assistance

I currently have a MS SQL server running on our local server and i need to connect a Android application to this SQL server

There are other computers and laptops already connecting to this server over WIFI

How would i do this and where can i find reading material for this

Comment: which technology is used for made a connection

Comment: on the current systems normal C# ado.net is used. I would like to connect to the the server without a webservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its already bridged. Emulator is using PC's net and if you are accessing through the Webservice then you need to change the URL according to that.

Like your live webservice name is :

http://www.google.com/Webservice.aspx

And if you are using it in local then for Android Emulator your URL will be

http://10.0.2.2:54674/Webservice.aspx

and for Genymotion

http://10.0.3.3:54674/Webservice.aspx

Comment: How would i do this without a webservice?